# how to find error in ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I use modal bootstrap to perform data input and processing with ajax but respone ajax always error. Whereas the data I send successful but must reload the web page.

This my modal and ajax:

```
<!-- Basic Examples -->
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="header">
                <h3 style="margin-bottom:15px">
                    <b>DAFTAR KATA SARA</b>                 
                </h3>
                <button type="button" name="modal_tambah1" id="modal_tambah2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataModal" class="btn btn-success">
                    TAMBAH
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="body" id="table_kata_sara">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>NO</th>
                            <th>Kata Sara</th>                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>                    
                    <tbody>
                    <?php 

                    $crud   = new Crud();
                    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM tb_kata_sara";
                    $result = $crud->fetchData($sql);
                    $no     = "1";

                    foreach ($result as $value) {

                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $no++."."; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value['kata_sara'];?></td>
                        </tr> 
                    <?php } ?>            
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- modal -->
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>TAMBAH KATA SARA</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" id="form_tambah_kata_sara">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Kata SARA</label>
                        <input type="text" name="kata_sara1" id="kata_sara2" placeholder="Kata SARA" class="form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit_kata_sara1" id="submit_kata_sara2" value="SIMPAN" class="btn btn-success"/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">BATAL</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#form_tambah_kata_sara').on('submit', function(){

        var kata_sara = $('#kata_sara2').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"Kata_sara/tambah_kata_sara.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:"kata_sara="+kata_sara,
            success:function(){
                // $('#table_kata_sara').load("index.php?p=kata_sara");
                console.log("sukses ");
            },
            error:function(){
                // $('#table_kata_sara').load("index.php?p=kata_sara");
                console.log("error ");
            }
        });  

    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

and this my proses insert data

```
$kata_sara = $_POST['kata_sara'];
$array_kata_sara = array('kata_sara' => $kata_sara);
$in = $crud->insertDatas("tb_kata_sara", $array_kata_sara);
```

Comment: I would think your page gets reloaded as you are not cancelling the default submit event. Do you see your `error` message in the console?

Comment: There are three parameters passed to the `error()` callback that you're ignoring: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  You can also check your browser's debugging tools to see the actual raw response from the server.

Comment: Yes, response always error

Comment: @FahruddinYusufHabibi: If the actual response coming from the server is just "error" then you're going to have to check the server-side code for problems.  You need to find out *what the error is* before you can correct it.  "Error" is not a particularly useful description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if there is an error on your php file , you can check like that

```
$.ajax({
            url:"Kata_sara/tambah_kata_sara.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:"kata_sara="+kata_sara,
            success:function(data){
                // $('#table_kata_sara').load("index.php?p=kata_sara");
                console.log(data);
            },
        error:function(){
            // $('#table_kata_sara').load("index.php?p=kata_sara");
            console.log("error ");
        }
        });
```